# Number of shortest paths on a grid from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ that don't go through (odd,odd) except perhaps $(m,n)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know that without restrictions there are $\binom{m+n}{n}$ such ways and i guess i should look at the number of paths that go through (odd,odd) but it seems to me that there are too many situations to check, is there a smart way to do this.
Also i found this [How many lattice paths are there from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2n)$ that avoids odd points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645312/how-many-lattice-paths-are-there-from-0-0-to-2n-2n-that-avoids-odd-point.But) this only avoids points on $(2i-1,2i-1)$ where for example $(1,3)$ is allowed.

Comment: You can split up the problem into smaller cases: find the number of paths that go through only (even, even), then (even, odd), then (odd, even). Can you do this?

Comment: @TobyMak: How can a path go through only (even,even)? It can never get started!

Comment: how can it only go through (odd,even)? if $m=4$ it surely has to pass some point $(x,y)$ with $x = 2$

Comment: I think you will find intuition if you draw a grid on paper. I would conjecture that it's the same as if you had $n/2$ and $m/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take away all the (odd,odd) points, and your grid looks like this:

[image: Grid with missing points]

Suppose first that $m$ and $n$ are both even. Then choosing a shortest path from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ is just the same as choosing a shortest path from $(0,0)$ to $(m/2,n/2)$ on a regular grid. This is $$\binom{(m+n)/2}{n/2}$$

Now suppose $m$ is even and $n$ is odd. Then to get to $(m,n)$ we must pass through $(m,n-1)$. So the number of shortest paths is $$\binom{(m+n-1)/2}{(n-1)/2}$$
with an analogous formula if $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

And if $m$ and $n$ are both odd, we must pass through $(m-1,n-1)$, after which we have a choice of two routes to $(m,n)$. So the number of shortest paths is $$2\binom{(m+n-2)/2}{(n-1)/2}$$